# How to remove require_once calls in a directory (Win)

Tags: windows, php, command-line-interface, zend-framework

This is a linux shell command which will comment all require_once calls from certain directory in php files:

```
  % cd path/to/ZendFramework/library
  % find . -name '*.php' -not -wholename '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
    -not -wholename '*/Application.php' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

But how could I do that in Windows OS cmd?

This is to speed up a Zend Framework application.

EDIT:

On one line:

```
find . -name '*.php' -not -wholename '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' -not -wholename */Application.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) and [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Comment: Is syntax the same? Tha above code does not work ("FIND: Parameter format not correct", "'-not' is not recognized as an inte
operable program or batch file.", "'xargs' is not recognized as an in
operable program or batch file.").

Comment: The backslash continuation operator is not usually found in cmd.exe I think. Remove them and input it as one continuous line.

Comment: "'xargs' is not recognized as an in operable program or batch file."

Comment: It is there in findutils. It might not be in your %PATH% though.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, on Windows, I could not get xargs working for some reason, but this is the command I ran through Git Bash shell:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

Then, manually recopy the Loader.php and Application.php file back over the sedited ones.